# How to show that $f(x_1,x_2)=e^{x_1^2}+e^{x_2^2}-x_1^2-x_2^2$ is coercive?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, coercive

I am trying to show $$f(x_1,x_2)=e^{x_1^2}+e^{x_2^2}-x_1^2-x_2^2$$ is a coercive function. I considered the inequality $e^a\geq 1+a \ \  \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$, so that
\begin{align}
e^{x_1^2}+e^{x_2^2}-x_1^2-x_2^2&\geq1+x_1^2+1+x_2^2-x_1^2-x_2^2 \\
&=2.
\end{align}

However, from this, I am unable to show that $f$ is coercive by the below definition $$\lim_{\|x\|\rightarrow\infty} f(x_1,x_2)=+\infty.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $$e^{x^2}\geq1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}.$$
By C-S we obtain:
$$e^{x_1^2}+e^{x_2^2}-x_1^2-x_2^2\geq2+\frac{x_1^4+x_2^4}{2}\geq2+\frac{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^2}{4}\rightarrow+\infty.$$

Comment: Why specifically $e^{x^2}\geq 1+x^2+x^4/2$? This did not seem immediately obvious to me.

Comment: @M B  Use the Taylor expansion for $e^x$: $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...$

Comment: Thanks for that. I am having difficulty understanding how you applied the C-S inequality. Are you able to add some explanation? (+1)

Comment: Also, isn't it enough that $$2+\frac{x_1^4+x_2^4}{2}\rightarrow +\infty,$$ for $\|x\|=x^4+y^4\rightarrow +\infty$.

Comment: @M B $\|x\|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ and $(x_1^2+x_2)^2\rightarrow+\infty$ for $\|x\|\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: But since all norms are equivalent on $\mathbb{R}^n$, can we not reduce the number of steps by considering the $4$-norm $(x_1^4+x_2^4)^{1/4}$? Since $(x_1^4+x_2^4)^{1/4}\leq x_1^4+x_2^4, \ \ (x_1^4+x_2^4)^{1/4}\rightarrow +\infty\implies x_1^4+x_2^4\rightarrow +\infty$ and so $$2+\frac{x_1^4+x_2^4}{2}\rightarrow +\infty.$$

Comment: @M B I think you are right. In any case, your problem is proved.

Answer (score 1):

Writing $f(x_1,x_2)=e^{\|x\|^2}e^{-x_2^2}+e^{x_2^2}-\|x\|^2$, fix $\|x\|$. Then $$\frac\partial{\partial x_2}(e^{\|x\|^2}e^{-x_2^2}+e^{x_2^2}-\|x\|^2)=-2x_2e^{\|x\|^2}e^{-x_2^2}+2x_2e^{x_2^2}=0$$ for a minimum which yields $x_2^2=\|x\|^2/2$. Note $x_2=0$ immediately yields $\lim\limits_{x_1\to\infty}f(x_1,0)=+\infty$. Substituting back yields $$\lim_{\|x\|\to\infty} f(x_1,x_2)\ge\lim_{\|x\|\to\infty}(e^{\|x\|^2}e^{-\|x\|^2/2}+e^{\|x\|^2/2}-\|x\|^2)=+\infty.$$